# How to create a Test scenario for a code block with Test not running check

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I am trying to test a section of code which runs only when the condition is [ If(!test.isRunning()) ] is true,

If I make a certain test case to run this code it won't go inside this if block as the condition is false.

```
if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't test that code. That's the explicit intention of the `!Test.isRunningTest()`. Code guarded by that condition will *never* run in an Apex unit test context.

For that reason, this structure is and should be used rarely in Apex code, and only for those code elements that absolutely cannot be executed in a unit test. One example is the `addFields()` call sometimes used in a Visualforce controller's constructor, which is not allowed in test context.

It is very rare to see more than one line of code guarded this way, and it makes me suspect the code is badly architected. With only a single line of code guarded, you can still get code coverage to 100% by writing the `if` and its body on a single line:

```
if (!Test.isRunningTest()) controller.addFields(new List<String> { 'Name' });
```

So long as the `if` test is run in a test, the entire line is counted as covered.

It used to be common to use this pattern to block callouts. In modern code, Mocks should be used instead.